# Dynamic Filter ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate

I have problem with Dynamic Filters in ASP.NET Boilerplate. Multi tenancy is off

Configuration.MultiTenancy.IsEnabled = false;

When I send query to DB  @DynamicFilterParam_000003 should be 1 as every Tenant Id in DB but it has value of 0.I tried every method given in ASP.NET Boilerplate documentations to set this parameter to 1 but nothing works and I can't disable this filters.This is part of the query in SQL Server Profiler:

```
FROM [dbo].[AbpRoles] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ((([Extent1].[TenantId] IS NULL) AND   (@DynamicFilterParam_000003 IS NULL))
 OR (([Extent1].[TenantId] IS NOT NULL) AND   (([Extent1].[TenantId] = @DynamicFilterParam_000003) OR 
  (([Extent1].[TenantId] IS NULL) AND (@DynamicFilterParam_000003 IS NULL)))) ) AND (([Extent1].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_000001) ) 
   AND (3 = [Extent1].[Id])',
  N'@DynamicFilterParam_000003 int,@DynamicFilterParam_000004 bit,@DynamicFilterParam_000001 bit,@DynamicFilterParam_000002 bit',     @DynamicFilterParam_000003=0,@DynamicFilterParam_000004=NULL,@DynamicFilterParam_000001=0,@DynamicFilterParam_000002=NULL
```